# Why does .sort() produce my output?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the given array

```
[ [ [ 'One' ], [ 'First', 'Fourth', 'Third' ] ],
  [ [ 'Three' ], [ 'First', 'Third' ] ],
  [ [ 'Two' ], [ 'First', 'Second', 'Third' ] ],
  [ [ 'One three' ], [ 'Fourth', 'Third' ] ],
  [ [ 'One two' ], [ 'Fourth', 'Second', 'Third' ] ],
  [ [ 'One two three' ], [ 'Second', 'Third' ] ] ]
```

and I want to sort it into this order in javascript:

```
[[["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
 [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]], 
 [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
 [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]]]
```

My belief is that a simple .sort() invocation will do the trick. Looking up the [w3schools documentation on .sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp), it says that

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.

Thus, I thought that the subarray holding the sub-subarray ['One'] would be placed at the top.

However, my output ends up being this:

```
[[["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["One two three"],["Second","Third"]], 
 [["One two"],["Fourth","Second","Third"]], 
 [["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]], 
 [["Three"],["First","Third"]], 
 [["Two"],["First","Second","Third"]]]
```

Why is that so? Why is the ["One"] placed in 4th place vs its preceding three? I don't know how to reason through that lexicographically. I even checked in the console that `["One"] < ["One three"]` and it returns `true`.

I am familiar with the technique of passing in a custom sorting function as an optional parameter to the .sort() function, but my expectation is that it wasn't necessary. Would appreciate an explanation, and perhaps guidance on what custom sorting function would be appropriate if it is necessary.

UPDATE:
Based on the helpful comments below I now see how my original intuition was wrong. Passing the below function into .sort() does the trick.

```
function sortFunction(a, b){
  if (a[0] < b[0]){
    return -1;
  } else if (a[0] > b[0]){
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: because as Strings, `" " < ","`

Comment: @adeneo OP wants to sort alphabetically.

Comment: It probably stringifies the arrays, so `'["One three"]'` comes before `'["One"]'`, as space goes before `"` etc.

Comment: It's sorting the lexicographic ordering of the stringified form the each array. You compared `["One"] < ["One three"]` but you never directly compare arrays that look like that in your sort. Instead compare `[["One"],["First","Fourth","Third"]] < [["One three"],["Fourth","Third"]]`